# How to emulate Netbeans' default Java EE environment on IntelliJ?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, intellij-idea

I'm doing an IDE comparison and I want to have the same development environment in both IDE's.

Netbeans comes with a default environment for developing Java EE apps, but it seems that I must pick each implementation of the Java EE standards (JPA, JAX-RS, etc), so, which implementations should I pick in order to have the same environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to pick implementations for Java EE Services. Netbeans comes bundled with [GlassFish Server](https://glassfish.java.net/). GlassFish have its own stack of libraries to provide Java EE services (EclipseLink for JPA, Jersey for JAX-RS, etc). So you don't really need to hand pick providers (you can, but you don't need to), just use what GlassFish gives you.

IntelliJ can also work with GlassFish (see [Developing Applications for GlassFish Server](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_GlassFish_Server) and [Getting Started with Java EE 7 and GlassFish 4.0](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Java+EE+7+and+GlassFish+4.0)). Enabling the desired facets (for JPA, JAX-RS, ec) is also a piece of cake.

So if you want a Full Blown Java EE Stack for both IDES just choose an Application Server and go ahead (since GlassFish comes bundled with Netbeans you can just use it, unless you have a specific App Server in mind).

You may also use a Maven Project (both IDES are really, really good with Maven) and hand pick any library you wish (as well as leveraging plugins for your App Server that can be used from inside the IDES).

Comment: So, in netbeans, if you pick GlassFish, you're ready to go; in IntelliJ you have to additionally specify the desired facets (for any picked server), but other than that, it should be the same in both?

Comment: "The same" is something strong to say, but yes, they will both be able to leverage GlassFish and its libraries (as well as several other app servers if you want) and both are fantastic tools that will certainly increase the productivity of Java EE Developers. Personally (as a Java Developer with a lot of experience) I love them both.